# Цвет фона Push Button, Label и т.д. меняется на цвет фона окна в приложении Qt Designer

Tags: css, qt-designer

Первоначально я установил background-image целиком на tab widget.

```
QTabWidget::pane
{
    border: 1px;
    background-image: url(:/Images/Images/tab_1_bg.jpg);
}
```

Тем самым у меня применился один фон ко всем QWidget. Но почему то он не отображался в самой программе, только на превью (это тоже проблема). Я не обратил на это внимание, но когда я захотел поменять фон отдельно для каждого QWidget, я столкнулся с тем, что цвет фона кнопок, лейблов и т.д. стал окрашиваться в цвет фона. Для каждого QWidget я применял background-image.
[image: Как теперь выглядят кнопки]

Как сделать так, что бы виджеты не окрашивались в цвет фона?

*P.s. Галочка fillbackground отключена, а если менять цвет фона именно виджетов (кнопки, лейбла), то он меняется только у границы (вместо белой)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, что бы исправить данную проблему, нужно менять фон через главный класс QTabWidget, с помощью данных строк:

```
#page1 
{
background-color: blue;
}

#page2 
{
background-color: red;
}
```

Где page1 и page2, название вкладок класса QWidget. У меня они называются tab_1 и tab_2.

Всё, если менять фон данными командами, то виджеты, которые вы будете добавлять, не буду окрашиваться в цвет фона!